# Random crash on presenting formsheet over MGSplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, crash

I am using MGSplitViewController in my application. 
From the one viewcontroller, On a button click, I have navigated control to these two methods where Formsheet will open with the background of MGSplitViewController (showing Master and Detail Views.)

These methods work well and I am getting the required result, but after many operations, the app crashes over this point without printing any log. Can anyone suggest me some solution?

```
-(void)launchSplitViewWithFormSheet :(MGSplitViewController *)mGSplitViewController
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mGSplitViewController];
    [self.baseNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navController]]; 
    [self openFormSheet:mGSplitViewController];
}

-(void)openFormSheet:(MGSplitViewController *)mGSplitViewController
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[mGSplitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *baseNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    detailViewController.masterViewController = detailViewController;

    baseNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [mGSplitViewController presentModalViewController:baseNavController animated:YES];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself got the answer. Instead of

```
[self openFormSheet:mGSplitViewController];
```

I called up the function with thread using

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(openPurpose:) withObject:mGSplitViewController waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and I am not getting random crash. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `alloc` several times in your code, but you aren't calling `release` or `autorelease` anywhere.  Every allocation of memory must be balanced by a release of memory.  If you don't do this, your application will leak memory and eventually crash.  Please read [the memory management section of Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for the reply. I released every object which was allocated. Still facing same problem.